# Building a portable external battery using 18650s with different capacities

Tags: batteries, battery-charging, bms

as the title said, I am planning to build an external usb power bank with 6 18650 lithium batteries. I also found this 6s BMS

[image]

[image]

The concern I am having is that, is it an issue if I use batteries that have different capacities? Thank you for answering and forgive my poor english|

EDIT: Instead of wiring in series, should I wire them in parallel instead? because the cells are 3.7v I think I can convert from 3.7v to 5.0v to charge phones

Comment: Why would you think about 6s connection

Comment: Bad idea. You want matched capacities of all batteries or the highest ones will be undercharged and the lowest ones over discharged unless you charge and discharge so slowly that the BMS balancing will have a chance to do anything.

Comment: @winny The BMS data sheet never says it can balance.

Comment: Then it’s even worse. Don’t! Rethink your project. You need cells with equal capacity and active balancing for any lithium battery pack.

Comment: Also, most if not all USB power banks use parallel connection of batteries so no balancing is required and cells can be of different capacities.

Answer (score 0):

Never use different capacity cells in a series battery pack.

And that is only a BMS. It only monitors ane protects the cells to shut down the pack when even one of the cells goes out of nominal range.

It does not charge, it does not balance. That's the job of the charger then to charge the cells in balance.

Comment: what should I get then? (not being passive aggressive)

Comment: @CaoDo Asking what to buy is off topic. Personally, I suggest to just buy a power bank. They should be safe if they are properly made. Building one with random components bough from online stores and old batteries may end up badly, mishandled batteries bursting into flames and starting fires.

Answer (score 0):

6s configuration with different cells is a bad idea for reasons that have been given already.  However, 6p (6 cells in parallel) might be ok.  LiPo cell voltage changes quite significantly as the cells charge and discharge, so they will tend to self-balance to a good degree and can then be considered more or less as one cell.  Take care when first connecting them up that they are charged to more or less the same voltage (50 to 100mV difference is probably ok).  For your application you’ll need a boost converter to step up to 5V

Comment: thanks for the answer, unfortunately I haven't found any 6p bms